# SQL - Difference between using "CROSS JOIN" and ","

Tags: sql

is there any difference between writing
`select * from R,S` and `select * from R CROSS JOIN S`?

Comment: Same result, different clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is.  The issue is semantically how the rest of the query is parsed.  So (according to the rules of standard SQL), I don't think the following works:

```
from a, b join
     c
     on a.x = c.x
```

The `,` stops the `a` from being recognized in the result of the `from` clause.

However, this does work:

```
from a cross join b join
     c
     on a.x = c.x
```

Note:  The first version might work in some databases.

Also, I strongly recommend that you never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  This is not about rules.  It is about writing clear code and being explicit about how your query is going to combine data from multiple tables.